# How to remove FullName header from PowerShell's dir output

Tags: powershell

I use Powershell 5.1.

The code:

```
$mysubfolders = dir $mystartpath | select FullName
```

gives me a listing of subfolders, but this listing has the header "FullName".

Because of this header, when I do:

```
Set-Location $mysubfolders[1]
```

I receive an error: a drive with the name "@{FullName=C" is not available.

How can I ignore or remove the "FullName" header?

Thanks!

Comment: `select FullName` --> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName`

Comment: when you run `Select-Object` and list one-or-more properties ... you get a new object with those props. you can do as `Theo` recommends and use the `-ExpandProperty` command to get the _value_ in that prop, OR you can use `$mysubfolders[1].FullName`, OR you can use `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -Directory).FullName` to get just the value in that one property.

Comment: Great to know this. Thank you, Lee_Dailey!

Comment: This problem had bothered me too. Thank you.